# ERROR: Current directory is not a meson build directory

Tags: windows, build, gtk4

I have been trying to install gtk4 on Windows 10, following the instructions from this site: https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/blog/2021/03/18/build-and-run-gtk-4-applications-with-visual-studio/.

After setting up the meson build with the command:

> C:\src\gtk>meson setup build --prefix C:/gnome

it shows the build directory at the very beginning of the build system
[(see picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzvcc.png).

I tried to compile the meson build with the following instruction:

> C:\src\gtk>meson compile -C build

However, I get this error note:

*ERROR: Current directory is not a meson build directory: `C:\src\gtk\build`.
Please specify a valid build dir or change the working directory to it.
It is also possible that the build directory was generated with an old
meson version. Please regenerate it in this case.*

Is there a way to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with pulseaudio.

Here running simply

```
meson build
```

creates the correct build directory. It was complaining about lots of missing libraries for developers (libsndfile-dev and so on) but after installing it, I was able to compile with

```
meson compile -C build
```

So did you check, that you work with the correct meson version of your tutorial link? Is the build directory correctly build? Does it even exist, are there any warnings left, when conifguring it?